# Error logging in Windows Application

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I have a Windows application and I want to log errors using Log4Net.

The issue I'm facing is *where* to log these errors. If I'm logging to a local folder then the logs will be on the clients' machine, which isn't conveniently accessible to us.

So, we thought of 2 options:

1. Log Error on a shared (network) location
2. Log Error in DB

The issue in logging errors in the DB is that if there is an issue in connecting to DB then logging obviously fails, so we decided to log on a shared location.

Now, someone informed me that it is not a good practice to log to a shared location.

What can you do to ensure logging when it's conceivable that every place you can log *might* be inaccessible or down?

Comment: It's only my opinion, but my point is you should rethink your question. Logs are very important but also need to be the simplest and reliable operation in your app. I suggest you to split the problem. 1) think a good way to log. (As you said "Log4Net".. so done). 2) think a way to acquire logs from your clients eg. a self hosted wcf service in your application which you can call from a server service

Comment: Hi Rajesh, I meant to leave a comment earlier when I answered, but I just got back to my desk. I've made [some edits](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25075031/2) to your question in order to make it easier to read, please review what I've changed to make sure it's still the question you want to ask, and you can get some formatting hints for your next question in the process. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

What shared location?

Generally you are always at risk of not getting the log, because the client machine can lose network connectivity. In this case logging to shared location, database, web service, whatever else remote is not going to help you.

Possible the least amount of friction professional solution would be to use a service like https://raygun.io/ It's not the only one there are other similar services.

Failing that, logging to a database is usually quite adequate. In practice if you *cant* log in the database it's because of one of the following:

- Connectivity problem. (Either the machine lost network connection or the DB server did or it's offline)
- A bug in the logging code

Again, in practice, the probability of the latter is quite small given adequate testing, since the logging code do not tend to be all that complicated. The former is much more probable, so you need to handle this scenario separately. Usually it's a good idea to log locally (local file / event log) if the database logging failed. It is difficult to retrieve this data from the customer machine, but in the rare case you need to troubleshoot a connectivity issue it's a life saver.

Logging to a "shared location" as in "windows share" is not common and in my opinion provide no advantage over logging to a database. Both database and shared location can be down. Client computer might not have connection. In all these scenarios both options behave the same.

In certain scenarios, it makes sense to upload the saved locally logfile to the database when network connectivity is restored, but often it's an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to accomplish is something that we call 'best effort' logging. It's a relatively language-agnostic practice that resembles:

```
try:
   if [database]
      log [database]
      done // exit the logging method, database worked.
   endif

   if [rsyslog] // If we got here, [database] didn't work.
      log [rsyslog]
      done // exit the logging method, rsyslog worked.
   endif

   if [redis] // If we got here, both [database] *and* [rsyslog] didn't work.
      log [redis]
      done // exit the logging method, redis worked.
   endif

finally: // nothing worked
   panic // write anywhere it can, just open a file in the app directory if it must.
```

That's up to you to implement around whatever logging library you wish to use, though some might conceivably have that built in. It only begins to look fragmented if things go badly, however:

- Most stuff will end up in the database
- Database exceptions will go to rsyslog (or any logging server)
- Using a third is just extra paranoia, watch redis for messages about rsyslog being existentially challenged (pub/sub might be ideal there)

.. or do it whatever way makes sense for you. If your *ideal* log location is the database, then just *log to the database*, while you ensure that you continue to make a 'best effort' if the database can't be reached. If all else fails, write to a file - you won't be doing it that often (or ideally, need to fish bits out of it) - so the location becomes much less of an issue.

The end result is, all you have to worry about doing is calling your logging method, since you know that it's going to make the *best effort possible* to log the data in one of several defined manners. If it gets to the point that it can't even open a file, well - you've probably got lots of other interesting logs to look into as well :)